# Github doesn't update pushes to branch and heroku

Tags: git, github, heroku

I am trying to maintain two branches: **master** and **production**.

All my regular work goes on master branch and when it's production ready I merge master to **production**.
I have uploaded my recent project to heroku for testing and faced quite some problems.

This are the commands I use to create, commit and push to master and then merge to production:

**1. Creating new branch**

```
git checkout -b production
```

**2. Making the local branch remote**

```
git push origin production
```

**3. Merging the master branch to production**

```
git merge origin/master
```

**Problem 1:** Now after all this if I check github I see my production branch has not been updated yet.

Same problem goes for heroku. After logging in with heroku using CLI following documentation and merging master to production do I have to push my changes to heroku as well?

I tried this:

```
git add.

git commit -am "comment for commit to heroku"

git push heroku master
```

**Problem 2:** But as I reach the commit stage it show working branch clean. How am I supposed to commit and push to heroku after I've merged master into production?

I tired the deploy with github but that's a whole lot painful since I cant check the logs if for some reason my application crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like Heroku is creating their own remote, which is different that GitHub.  So yes, you do need to push to both.

If you run `git remote -v` you can see the remote repositories associated with your repo.

From the Heroko documentation: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git you should see something like this.

[image]

Note the `git.heroku.com`.

If you want to also push to GitHub, you'll need to create a new remote for GitHub and then explicitly push to each remote.

From the GitHub docs, https://docs.github.com/en/github/using-git/adding-a-remote,

[image]

Once you have both remotes registered in your repository you'd run:

```
git checkout production
git push heroku
git push origin
```